# In spark how to abstrat the array from an struct and create a new field with it

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a struct with schema:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- products: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- updated_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- product_color: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- updated_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- products_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- orders_id: long (nullable = true)
```

Now, I want to create a new column with product_color so in my data frame I am adding a new column like

```
  df.withColumn("product_color", col(currentNode + "." + fieldName))
```

With new column the schema:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- products: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- updated_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- product_color: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- updated_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- products_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- orders_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- product_color: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- updated_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- products_id: long (nullable = true)
```

If you look at the schema for product_color, an element of the array is added.

```
|-- element: array (containsNull = true)
```

I am looking for help to understand how can create the new column with the exact schema as it is inside the product struct.

Expected Schema:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- products: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- updated_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- product_color: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- updated_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- products_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- orders_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- product_color: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- updated_at: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- products_id: long (nullable = true)
```

Spark: 2.4.5
Language: Scala

Comment: could you add expected output schema?

Comment: Added the expected schema @Shu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While adding as `new column` **explode** the array to get your desired schema.

**`Example:`**

```
//sample df schema

df.printSchema
//root
// |-- id: long (nullable = true)
// |-- products: array (nullable = true)
// |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
// |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- order_id: long (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- product_color: array (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
// |    |    |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |    |-- products_id: long (nullable = true)

df.withColumn("product_color",explode(col("products.product_color"))).printSchema
//root
// |-- id: long (nullable = true)
// |-- products: array (nullable = true)
// |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
// |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- order_id: long (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- product_color: array (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
// |    |    |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
// |    |    |    |    |-- products_id: long (nullable = true)
// |-- product_color: array (nullable = true)
// |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
// |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- products_id: long (nullable = true)
```